# Rounding of the millisecond part in Linux datetime

Tags: linux, bash, datetime, awk, timestamp

So I have the date format like this : **2019-10-19 23:55:42.797** and I want the millisecond part to be round of into the second so the output should look something like this: **2019-10-19 23:55:43**

I have tried

> `date -d "2019-10-19 23:55:42.797" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

but it's giving me output like **2019-10-19 23:55:42**

How should I do this in **Linux** bash shell?

Comment: What is the date command available? GNU or BSD? output of `date --version`?

Comment: hii @Inian date (GNU coreutils) 8.31. its GNU.

Comment: @kvantour I think the behaviour is correct. After noon we do not change date, because we are nearer to next day. Days, minutes, seconds are more like periods (intervals) then numbers. Note: this doesn't invalidate the question, it is a sensible things to get, just not the most common case.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi yes I figured out it is not a bug. Rounding just does not make sense in absolute time. The format specifiers represent the actual time quantity. Imagine we start using rounding when we do the new year countdown, the year would start half a second early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in a single `awk` like this:

```
s='2020-12-31 23:59:59.501'
awk -F. 'gsub(/[-:]/, " ", $1) {
   dt = mktime($1)
   if ($2 >= 500) dt++
   print strftime("%F %X", dt)
}' <<< "$s"
```

```
2021-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: hii Anubava, Thanks for the solution. But whenever i am trying this with this value (2019-11-19 23:30:08.284) its giving me something like this: 2019-11-19 23:30:8.

Comment: Please give me your result for the date "2020-12-31 23:59:59.501", you are up for a surprise ;-)

Comment: The fix is not easy in shell: there are also valid leap seconds (so :23:59:60.789) and without time-offset (time zone), it is impossible to predict when it happens (23:59:60 happens just in UTC) -- correction: "+%s %N" may help before using calculation. But unix time doesn't takes into account leap seconds. Maybe it is not a problem in the OP case

Comment: @kvantour Please check updated answer that uses `mktime and `strftime` to address date/time computations.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Linux systems don't keep track of leap seconds as it would not know how to handle a leap second from an epoch point of view. For date, 23:59:60 is equivalent to "00:00:00" while from a leap-second perspective, they are two different times. Unix systems run on UTC with a slow drift near leap-seconds, they don't run on TDB

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you observe is as expected. The format specifiers represent the actual quantity without rounding. Imagine you would include rounding and you have the time "2019-10-19 23:55:42.797" but you are not interested in seconds and set the format to "%F %H:%M", do you want to see "2019-10-19 23:55" or "2019-10-19 23:56", and even further. Imagine you have the time "2020-12-31 23:59:59.501" with format "%F %T", do you want it to show "2021-01-01 00:00:00" or "2020-12-31 23:59:59". While we all want 2020 to finish as soon as possible, the latter still remains the correct time representation.

Rounding in times is only relevant when you look at time differences and not at absolute times. Hence, I strongly recommend not to implement any rounding and just use the output that `date` provides you.

However, if, for whatever reason you actually need to round the time to the nearest second, then you can do this:

```
epoch_ms=$(date -d "2019-10-19 23:55:42.797" "+%s%3N")
epoch=$(( (epoch_ms + 500)/1000 ))
date -d "@$epoch" "%F %T"
```

Or in a single line:

```
date -d "@$(( ( $(date -d "2019-10-19 23:55:42.797" "+%s%3N") + 500 )/1000 ))" "+%F %T"
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That sheds more light on why we shouldn't use rounding.